# Why does the roc gem generate an error when I do `require 'roc'`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, roc

Learning to use the `roc` gem, I run a simple program below and keep getting errors. Pretty sure my Ruby and gem versions are up to date. Can't see what I'm doing wrong.

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    2: from PDaucT.rb:2:in ''
>     1: from
>   /Users/royxxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
>   /Users/royxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- roc (LoadError)

My code:

```
require 'matrix'
require 'roc'
aucdata = Matrix[ [0.9, 1], [0.8, 1] ]
print "Test of basic code"
puts
```

Comment: The obvious very first diagnostic step would be to check whether `roc` is installed.

Comment: since I had downloaded it, and saw it was installed earlier, and it doesn't show up now, I assume that when I updated versions (because the gem didn't run) i changed something that now needs fixing.  I'll try installing it again.

Comment: I installed it again, it now shows up when I run gem list, but I still get (even more) errors when run the program.

Comment: I wonder if this error message means there is something wrong with the gem?

Comment: /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/roc-1.0.0/lib/roc.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
               when 'N' : curpoint[0]+=xstep

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct gem? The [roc](https://github.com/fredrikj/roc) gem seems a bit outdated. Were you maybe looking for [redis-roc](https://github.com/benlund/roc) ?

Comment: I would like to repeat [Виктор's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366967/why-does-gem-matrix-not-generate-an-error-but-roc-does?noredirect=1#comment103085966_58366967):  The gem uses syntax that was removed from Ruby **TWELVE YEARS AGO**. Are you 100% sure that you want to use a gem that hasn't been maintained **IN A DECADE**?

Comment: redis-roc, is about Redis, not about Receiver Operator Characteristics and the Area Under the curve.  There is another more recent gem by the same author, rroc, that does run without errors HOWEVER my test of it yielded a non-sensical answer (an AUC of infinity) so I sent email to the author but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Thank you, Jörg for identifying that the problem was the gem, not something about my computer.